# My Image wont show up

Tags: html, image

I checked to be sure that I have an image folder on the same level as my html file, but the image won't show.

NOLA Montessori

```
<body>

<p>
    <img src=Images\"Photo1.jpg" alt="Montessori Classroom" width="500" height="250">
</p>


<q>"Free the child's potential and you will transform him into the world."</q>
    <i>Maria Montessori</i>
```

Comment: try changing `src=Images\"Photo1.jpg"` to `src="Images/Photo1.jpg"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes need to be surrounding the whole URL to the image and not just the "Photo1.jpg" part. Also you should use forward slashes for websites ("/" instead of "\"). For example:

```
<img src="Images/Photo1.jpg" alt="Montessori Classroom" width="500px" height="250px">
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the quotes can solve your problem..

```
<img src="Images/Photo1.jpg" alt="Montessori Classroom" width="500px" height="250px">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misplaced  the double quotes `img src=Images\"Photo1.jpg"` this will not work:

Try this :

```
<body>

<p>
    <img src="Images/Photo1.jpg" alt="Montessori Classroom" width="500" height="250">
</p>


<q>"Free the child's potential and you will transform him into the world."</q>
    <i>Maria Montessori</i>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The double quotes must surround the whole url like this

```
<img src="Images/Photo1.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try the following see if it helps ..

```
<body>
  <p>
<img src="Images/Photo1.jpg" alt="Montessori Classroom" width="500" height="250" />
 </p>

<q>"Free the child's potential and you will transform him into the world."</q>
<i>Maria Montessori</i>
</body>
```